# Firebase - Best practices & cost management - Collection Map Array or sub collection

Tags: arrays, flutter, firebase

I am creating two pages. The first one will contain a listview.builder, displaying a list of shops (supermarket #1, supermarket #2,...). Each record will be displayed on a card.
Then, if the user tap on one card, the user will see an other page displaying all the items he is supposed to buy (this is not an eCommerce app, but it is more an herand or shopping list).
The items could be for example [itemName: Sugar , itemChecked: No][itemName: Beer, itemChecked:yes]...
The itemChecked is used to cross the product you have bought already.

My question is what should be my data structure to make this easy to query and also to reduce the Firebase cost? Bellow, you will see two images of what I have done, but I am not sure if I am respecting the best practices. I have read the Firebase user guide, but it is not clear to me what I should do.
Please, can you advise? Many thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is `Firestore` ( no mention in the question)
What you are doing is you are putting all your data in a single document.

And yes, this is the best approach if your requirement is reducing the cost.

However, you will have to download the entire database everytime the user uses the app.

That could be an issue if:

- Your list can grow up to thousands of supermarket and list items

And

- User mobile data is limited
- User internet is slow

Also  note that a single Firestore document has a maximum of roughly 1Mb size.

This means at some point, you document will be full.

What you can do is create a second document when it's full, then third, and so one... This will require more code and some good testing. But it works. I used this approach in some of my projects.

This is the best approach to reduce cost, but not the best in terms of maintainability and architecture.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that in FirebaseFirestore, there is subcollection. Would this also a good option?

Comment: No, subcollection are just there to structure your database in a meaningful way. You will be billed for each document read/write/delete anyways

Comment: OK. If we put the cost on a side, I would like to get access to the records easily. I am not yet very familiar with snapshot. I am using it when it is with one document containing few fields. But when I  have an array containing maps, I do not know to how display the data. Please, can you advise? Thank you